# TFS 2012 find all authors on a file

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to find all authors across all branches for a particular file?
Right click view history kind of does this but if the original author is different than the person checking in the merge, it becomes hard to find.  Particularly if the history is deep.

Comment: you mean "author = everyone who modifed" the particular file?

Comment: Yes, every/any one who has modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the trunk branch and then use the [ANNOTATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx) option. This will show you all the users who modified the particular file (along with the changeset details), including the lines which they modified visually in your IDE.

If you want to use this from the command line, please go ahead and install the [Team FOundation Power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f). 
Please find below the usage:

> tfpt annotate /?
>
> Displays the given version of a file along with information on who
>   modified the line last.
>
> Usage: tfpt annotate [/noprompt] filespec[;versionspec]
>
> filespec               Server or local path of file to view history of.
>
> /noprompt              Prints interleaved output to console
>   instead of GUI.

Comment: Perfect thank you.  "At the trunk branch" is the key in my use case.